# Paged scrollView with several tableViews

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

I'm trying to create a viewController with a segmentedControl, which handle 3 different type of content. I've found this triggy since all 3 segments is hookd up to different JSON api's and this seem to conflict with eachother I've therefor come to the conclusion that it might be better to create a paged scrollView which contain 3 different tableViews and then hook the segmentedControl to this. My question is then how can i using swift create a paged ScrollView which contain 3 different viewControllers/tableViews?

Comment: Have you thought using a `UIPageViewController` embedded in a `UIViewController` with the segmented control.

Comment: Not sure this is possible when i want a segmentControl under the navigationBar?

Comment: Sure it's possible. You'll have a container view controller that will hold the segmentControl and the UIPageViewController.